# Copying Empty's coordinates & rotation exactly to the camera

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend4web

I'm using blender & blend4web to show a device view wherein which the user is allowed to click on front view & back view buttons to trigger those views respectively. I have 2 empties for front and back views to which the camera moves to on click of these buttons.

This all works well. Only problem is that when clicking on these buttons after panning, at times, the camera becomes inverted!

I'm using this setup in my blend4web logic node editor:

[image]

I suspect the camera gets inverted at times after panning due to not retaining the rotation of the empty. How do I copy the empties' exact rotation to the camera?